# Clicking IMG targets the DIV near it using Jquery's $(this). $(this) being the IMG clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click my IMG tag and have it select the last DIV tag below it with the class "comment-text" using Jquery

```
  <div class="one-comment hill">
    <h4 class="name-title">Durdan Moraan</h4>
    <**img** src="pencil-grey.png" class="edit-icon">
    <div class="date-box">   
      <div class="month">
        Mar
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        27
      </div>
      <div class="time">
        11:11 am
      </div>
    </div>
    **<div class="comment-text">**
      Ok this is the comment. 
    **</div>**
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.comment-text` div is the sibling of your image. You can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('img.edit-icon').click(function(){
    var commentDiv = $(this).siblings('.comment-text');
    // You can use commentDiv with other jQuery method now 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**siblings()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) as `.comment-text` is sibling of image. or you can use

```
$('img.edit-icon').click(function(){
    var commentTextDiv = $(this).siblings('.comment-text:last'); //select last .comment-text div
    var commentText = commentTextDiv.html();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Swv/)

*OR*

You can use [**.nextAll()**](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
$('img.edit-icon').click(function () {

    var commentTextDiv = $(this).nextAll('.comment-text:last'); //select div
    var commentText = commentTextDiv.html();
    alert(commentText)
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Swv/1/)

Comment: +1 I'd also use `:last` for the sibling selector, as the OP mentioned: `select the last DIV tag...`

Comment: @HashemQolami, Thanks incorporated

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('img.edit-icon').click(function () {
    var myElement = $(this).next('.comment-text')
    //myElement is the div you want
});
```